# Cordova login with facebook

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am a beginner in develop cordova ,i use this exemple

https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-facebook-example but in error are

display :!JavaScript ERROR: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'e.hasOwnProperty')
http://localhost:58578/js/ng-cordova.min.js:10

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you are running it inside the browser where the facebook app doesnt not exits. In that case you need to run it on real device (not emulator) where you have the facebook app installed and the error should be gone.

Comment: ok thanks for this response ,now when I run in the device emulateur another error is display :

Comment: ok thanks for this response ,now when I run in the device emulateur for this commande ligne : (ionic run android )another error is display :(

Comment: Error code 1 for command: /home/binov1/workElolinkMobile/ElolinkProject/platforms/android/gradlew

Comment: with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/binov1/workElolinkMobile/ElolinkProject/platforms/android/build.gradle,-PcdvBuildArch=arm,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true

Answer (score 0):

The example you are trying, dont open the Facebook-App to Auth. it is opening a inAppBrowser it just work in your device of emulator